# CSS responsive absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu whose position should be depending on the height of the header. The height of the header varies by content, the font-size and the padding set by media queries in dependence of viewport height.

HTML:

```
<header>
  <p>Example</p>
  <nav>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

@media(max-height: 500px) {
  header {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

nav {
  background-color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 82px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

Imagine `nav` is the folded out dropdown menu.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjufc63b/2/

If you decrease your window's height below 500 pixels it appears a white gap between header and nav, which should not be so. Also if you change your browser's font size.

Is there a solution to get the dropdown menu always below the header independent of the header's height and also above the other content (what absolute positioning does) without using javascript and wihout moving the `nav` outside `header`?

Comment: The `nav` should automatically move to top and close the gap without the need to redefine the margin with the `top` css property in media query. In this example I could do it, yes, but I can't define the `top` margin if the headers height changes because of the font-size or height of content.

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood your question. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the top to 100%, outside of the media query

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

@media(max-height: 500px) {
  header {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

nav {
  background-color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Example</p>
  <nav>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Nice. I got too caught up in media query solution, that I forgot the most general one :)

Comment: Easy and clean solution.. shame on me. Thank you!

Comment: @Armin  Thanks to both .  Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 3):

Inside your media query for under 500px height, remove fixed top margin from `nav` element.

```
@media(max-height: 500px) {
  header {
    padding: 0;
  }
  header > nav {
    top: auto;
  }
}
```

Actually you can also do it by default, outside of your media query. Define top margin as auto. This way you won't have to care about fixed value

```
nav {
  background-color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto
  width: 100%;
}
```

Since your `header` is fixed it won't push other elements, so in order to do so you need to add space to inner elements. For example:

```
header {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

header p{
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

If you remove padding from `header` and add it to your inner `p` element, it will push your `nav`. But in general for more content you can create a new wrapper element inside that will work as "space-taker".

Comment: The solution for the media query works, but I need an universal solution if `header`'s height is changed by font-size or content. Your second solution will omit the padding bottom.. see https://jsfiddle.net/mjufc63b/3/

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, check @vals answer for alternative.